# Que puedo hacer para sacar el mayo precio y la menor cantidad

Tags: java

Hola buenas noches podrian ayudarme estoy comenzando con esto de la programacion y quisiera saber como puedo sacar las cantidades mayores y menores necesito sacar el mayor precio y la menor catidad de que manera podria hacerlo  en este programa.
Hola buenas noches podrian ayudarme estoy comenzando con esto de la programacion y quisiera saber como puedo sacar las cantidades mayores y menores necesito sacar el mayor precio y la menor catidad de que manera podria hacerlo  en este programa.Hola buenas noches podrian ayudarme estoy comenzando con esto de la programacion y quisiera saber como puedo sacar las cantidades mayores y menores necesito sacar el mayor precio y la menor catidad de que manera podria hacerlo  en este programa.

```
              //Main
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Invetario invetario = new Invetario();
    
    Producto prod = invetario.getProducto(101);
    System.out.println(prod.getDescripcion());
    System.out.println(prod.getCantidad());
    System.out.println(prod.getPrecio());
    System.out.println(prod.calcularPrecioVenta());




            //Producto
public class Producto {
private int codigo;
private String descripcion;
private double precio;
private int cantidad;

public Producto() {
    
}

public Producto(int codigo, String descripcion, double precio, int cantidad) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}


public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public int getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}
public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}
public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}
public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}
public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}
public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public double calcularPrecioVenta() {
    return this.precio + this.precio * 0.14;
}
}





//Inventario
public class Invetario {

private Producto[] inventario = new Producto[4];

public Invetario() {
    Producto prod1 = new Producto();
    prod1.setCodigo(100);
    prod1.setDescripcion("producto 1");
    prod1.setPrecio(10.00);
    prod1.setCantidad(20);
    
    Producto prod2 = new Producto(101, "producto 2", 20.00, 100);
    
    inventario[0] = prod1;
    inventario[1] = prod2;
    inventario[2] = new Producto(103, "producto 3", 30.00, 50);
    inventario[3] = new Producto(104, "producto 4", 25.00, 10);
    
}

public Producto getProducto(int codigo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inventario.length; i++) {
        if(codigo == inventario[i].getCodigo()) {
            return inventario[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
        
}
public Producto getProductoMayorPrecio(int codigo) {
                    
}
    
}
    return null;
}
public Producto getProductoMenorCantidad() {
    
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El mayor y menos precio de que? y la pagina te decia que tenias mucho codigo, porque es exactamente eso.. tiraste todo el codigo en la pregunta, sin especificar donde tenes el probema...

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo estas tratando de retornar de los métodos un **Producto**

La forma más simple es recorrer el array de productos **inventario** uno a uno y buscar el de menor cantidad (o el de mayor precio).

Son necesarias variables locales auxiliares para la **cantidad (o precio)** y para la referencia del objeto Producto a retornar.

Se compara la **variable auxiliar cantidad** inicializada en 0 ( o -1 si puede haber productos con cantidad 0 en el inventario) con la **cantidad del Producto** en la posición actual del array **inventario**.

Cuando encuentre un objeto con una cantidad menor a la cantidad actual en la variable auxiliar cambiar: el valor de la variable auxiliar por el encontrado  y guardar la referencia del objeto actual en la referencia auxiliar.

Terminado el recorrido retornar la referencia auxiliar;( alternativamente usar una variable auxiliar int que guarde el indice del objeto de menor cantidad y retornar la referencia original).

```
    public Producto getProductoMenorCantidad() {
    int cantidad = 0; 
    // int indice; // para guardar el indice del objeto en lugar de la referencia
    Producto aux = new Producto();
    
    for( int i = 0 ; i < inventario.length ; i++) {

        if(inventario[i].getCantidad() > cantidad) {
            cantidad = inventario[i].getCantidad();
            aux = inventario[i];
        }
    }
     return aux;
}
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que la referencia que retornas puede cambiar el estado del objeto Producto al que hace referencia. ( No es una buena practica en general )

```
Inventario in = new Inventario();

Producto meCantidad = in.getProductoMenorCantidad(); // obtengo el producto con menor cantidad

System.out.println("Cantidad: "+meCantidad.getCodigo()+" cantidad: "+meCantidad.getCantidad());

meCantidad.setCantidad(500); // moficación de la cantidad original

System.out.println("codigo: "+in.getProducto( meCantidad.getCodigo()).getCodigo()+" cantidad: "+in.getProducto( meCantidad.getCodigo()).getCantidad());
```

Alternativa con for mejorado (for each):

```
    public Producto getProductoMenorCantidad() {
    int cantidad = 0;
    Producto aux = new Producto();
    
    for( Producto p : inventario) {
        if(p.getCantidad() > cantidad) {
            cantidad = p.getCantidad();
            aux = p;
        }
    }
     return aux;
}
```

El otro método lo dejo para que lo hagas es similar, cambia un detalle.